# Java RMI Registry.lookup() - no response

Tags: java, networking, client-server, rmi, connection-timeout

I am experiencing an error which I am at a loss to explain. I feel like I'm so close but I just can't seem to get a connection.

I have setup two RMI server objects on a remote server and I want to connect to and use these. I am able to connect to the RMIRegistry on the server on port 1099 and with the call Registry.list() I get the correct names of the stubs which are setup on the server.

Now for my code...

**Server object 1**

```
Registry registry = null;
try {
    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
} catch (RemoteException e){
    System.out.println("Registry already exists - connecting...");
    try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
        String[] objects = registry.list();
        for (int n=0; n<objects.length; n++){
            System.out.println(objects[n]);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("RMI registry connection fail.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

BioBingoLogic bb = null;
bb = new BioBingoLogic();
BioBingoInterface bbStub = null;
try {
    bbStub = (BioBingoInterface)
    UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(bb, 9753);
} catch (RemoteException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("RemoteServer export fail.");
    System.exit(1);
}

try {
    registry.rebind("BioBingoServer", bbStub);
} catch (RemoteException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Registry rebind fail.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

**Server object 2**

Completely the same as **Server object 1** only exported on port 9754 and called "DatabaseServer".

**Output**

My output from these two objects is in the following picture:

[Output from running the two server objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lowE.png)

**Client side**

The server objects work as I expect them to. It is the Client which doesn't seem to be able to connect to the individual server objects.

```
System.out.println("Creating RMI Registry stub.");
Registry remoteRegistry = null;
try {
    remoteRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("biobingo", 1099);
    String[] objects = remoteRegistry.list();
    System.out.println("\nObjects in stub:");
    for (int n = 0; n < objects.length; n++) {
        System.out.println(objects[n]
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Connecting to BioBingoServer object.");
    try {
        game = (BioBingoInterface) remoteRegistry.lookup("BioBingoServer");
        db = (DatabaseInterface) remoteRegistry.lookup("DatabaseServer");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Stub not found.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Registry not found.");
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("Connected to BioBingoServer.");
System.out.println("Connected to DatabaseServer");
```

*biobingo* is the IP of the remote server registered with the alias in my hosts file.

**Output**

This is where the problem arises....

I get the output in the following picture:

[Output from client side application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt5er.png)

It should be understood from the picture, that I never get an exception of any kind. It just hangs on the call *Registry.lookup()* until it, I suppose, gets a timeout from the server and executes the next part of the client code - calls to the server object then throws a *RemoteException*.

It should be noted that the remote server is behind a NAT, however, the NAT and its firewall is setup to allow all incoming **TCP** traffic, from all IP's, on all the specified ports; **1099** + **9753** + **9754**.
I have also verified that the ports are indeed open with a port scanner.

This is where I am at a loss...

**Any suggestions to what is preventing me from connecting to the server objects, when I am entirely able to connect to the RMIRegistry?**

Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you!

> **---------------------------------------------**
>   **EDIT**
>   **---------------------------------------------**

I tried running the server objects and client with the java vm option:

`-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel=VERBOSE`

The following picture shows the output and includes description of the flow and where the possible error occurs:

[output with java vm option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5NQh.jpg)

**Client output**

No output, just a 3 minute delay on `Registry.lookup()`. Afterwards the following code is executed and then on function calls to the RMI stub there’s a 3 minute delay followed by a `ConnectException` saying *connection timed out to 10.230.56.71` (which is the local IP of the server, although I’m connecting to it’s global IP - so it seems that my call does find it’s way to the NAT which the server is behind).

**Server output**

Nothing, really.

Comment: What is the Ctrl/C in the server output?

Comment: Can you please run your server and client with `-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.logLevel=VERBOSE` and post the results in your question?

Comment: Ctrl+C is just the interrupt signal to the process, however, because of the ‘&’ in the end of the command the process keeps running. I’ll try that run option later and post it here - thanks!

Comment: @user207421 I have now edited the post and added the output with the jvm option in the end.

Comment: @user207421 I just thought it was more descriptive and contextual with an image - and I’m not allowed to post pictures inline because I need “reputation”... I have updated the post with the output I’m experiencing, though it’s not much I’m getting from the run-option.

Comment: Bad luck. Posting it here is a rule of StackOverflow, and also of mine.

Comment: I am having this issue also. Did you find an answer?

Comment: This is item A.1 of the RMI FAQ. @tokyo